# Store a value in a UI control vs. in a separate variable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

May I know what is the benefit of creating a variable for a control in VB.NET?

For example:

1. I access the `TextBox` value by using `textBox.Text`.
2. I declare a variable to store the value of the `TextBox`. Then, I access the value through the variable.

Which approach is better and more flexible?

Comment: i would use the  `TextBox.Tag` property

Comment: @0699: I suppose that's a feasible approach. The problem with it usually becomes clear during maintenance, especially when someone other than the original coder takes over maintenance: The `Tag` property has no predefined, fixed meaning, it can be used for any and all purposes. So whoever will look at your code will have to guess from type casts and context what `Tag` might have been used for. A similar approach would be to derive from e.g. `TextBox` and add a properly-typed, single-purpose property whose name is somewhat more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches work. I personally tend towards the latter scenario (separate variables):

Using controls such as a `TextBox` as the single location that holds your business data is frowned upon by some people. This becomes especially problematic in practice if you have to first parse the value whenever you access it (turning a string representation back into an object), or format it (turning the object into a string representation) when you want to display it. In that case, I would decide to store the actual value separately from the control, so that all the parsing and formatting logic can be concentrated into one place, without having to repeat it all over your codebase.

On the other hand, storing values in separate variables introduces the need to keep that variable in sync with the control. That is exactly what [**Data Binding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984099.aspx) is good for. I'm assuming your question is about Windows Forms, where Data Binding is somewhat limited (but often sufficient). However, if your UI is based on WPF or Silverlight, Data Binding is much more powerful (e.g. it can automatically parse/format via `IValueConverter`) and can save you lots of trouble. (If you find Data Binding too complex, you can always the same work manually, though that will mean subscribing to lots of `…Changed` events. )

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, stakx, I guess I got the sense on it. For example, every value that get via the TextBox.Text is belong to a string which means we need to do the conversion if the value need to be used for calculation. However, by using the variable, I can use some events such as TextChanged event to try parse the value into the certain format and update to the variable whenever there is a text changing for calculation purpose. Thus, in the future, when I need to do the calculation, I just need to use the variable instead of convert the TextBox.Text into numeric again.